# Where at last, can I learn how to code and decode a QR code to implement it myself?

Tags: encoding, qr-code, implementation

I cab't find anything about how QR codes are made/coded. If I would want to make an own piece of code that creates QR codes, where could I find documentation of the QR code structure to be able to do it?

There seems to be an information hole in the internet, and it is nit possible to find anything like that.

Comment: I've wrote my QR code generator with this tutorial http://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/. But actually why do you want to write it yourself instead using any of existing libraries?

Comment: Umm, there are lots of sources explaining the QR code thoroughly. Where did you look? I've implemented readers and writers years ago already with the information available.